# Android : Using Listfragment instead of Fragment

Tags: java, android, list

i'm making a news app which in the news activity i have a tab slider with 2 tabs called , "new news" - "random or top news". which each tabs content are fragment.(i hope u get me!).

but the problem is im using a code to parse the this page content > http://aliak.xzn.ir/rap/get_all_products.php (i think u findout what site code im using)...

the problem is that if i want to show this in fragment(not activity) i have to write this code:

```
public class tab1 extends ListFragment {}
```

instead of this :

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {}
```

and i the pager adapter i have problem which tells me the listfragment is not accepted! and if i dont use list fragment i have many errors!

**THE CODES FOR APP :**

my tab1 fragment ::

```
public class tab1 extends ListFragment {

    //static final String url_all_products = "http://aliak.xzn.ir/rap/get_all_products.php";
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // JSON Node names


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);


        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("درحال دريافت اخبار،کمي صبر کنيد!");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }


            /**
             * getting All products from url
             */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://aliak.xzn.ir/rap/get_all_products.php", "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                Main.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * *
             */

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                                new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name});
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }


        }


        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();


        return v;

    }


}
```

my adapter class :

```
/**
* Created by hp1 on 21-01-2015.
*/
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which   are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    if (position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        tab1 tab1 = new tab1();
        return tab1;
    } else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        tab2 tab2 = new tab2();
        return tab2;

    }


}
/*


*/


// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

**IF U NEEDED MORE CODES JUST TELL ME  , ILL ANSWER IN 2 MIN TOPS!**

Comment: All tabs in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter  need to be of the same type, so your only solution here is to just make it a Fragment with a ListView inside it, unless you want both tabs to be ListFragments.

Comment: @DanielNugent , woooooow u just solved it! when the app made up ill put ur name in it! ill warn u , thanks so much!

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

check your imports and make sure your Fragment and ListFragment come from the same package, i.e. both android.support.v4.app.Fragment/ListFragment or both android.app.Fragment/ListFragment. Whichever one you use it has to be consistent with your actual fragment class implementations.

Comment: nope i triyed all of these and im always sure aboud impots.

Comment: and you're absolutely sure that you're importing FragmentStatePagerAdapter, FragmentManager, Fragment, and ListFragment from support (or neither)? Could you post the error your IDE gives you when you try to return ListFragment?

Comment: yes iam sure i imported from the support v4 , and the problem is that it ( when i hold on the return i think). >> required : import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;     found:import rappage.rapfarsi.media.appteam.tab1; and i have impoted listfragment even , i did all , everything ... but if i use in a java activity not fragment i have no error none...

Comment: and what does the first line in your ListFragment say please? It starts with package xxx.xxx.xxx;

Comment: packages are the same i checked them and i know that i gonna warn me if its not same as app.

Comment: i know that much at least

Comment: i know it is wired but the app is going to have 100,000  visiters at least at start its first news app for persian rap, aanyone solve it ill put name in app as the 1 , beside its important for me fix it...